# Get every second row as a result table in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm looking for a t-sql script that returns a list, that shows every second value from a grouping from Table1.

For example I have the following data (Table1) and want the desired result-list:

```
Table1:
Customer    Quantity
A           5
A           8               (*)
B           3
B           5                (*)
B           11
C           7
D           4
D           23               (*)
```

Desired retult-list:

```
Customer    Quantity
A           8
B           5
D           23
```

I think about doing something something with 'select distinct and left outer join', but I can't get it to work. Possibly I need an row numbering, but can't figure out how to do it. Anyone can help me?

Beneath is the script I used to make and fill Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(Customer nvarchar(1) NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Table1(Customer,Quantity)
VALUES 
('A',5),
('A',8),
('B',3),
('B',5),
('B',11),
('C',7),
('D',4),
('D',23);
```

Comment: what DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Which order makes a row a second row? Do you order by quantity?

Comment: for now I wanted it ordered by quantity, but in real live It would be order by date (which I haven't added in the example). So the answers given by Mureink and Horia will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CTE`:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Quantity) rn
    FROM    @Table1 
)
SELECT Customer, Quantity
FROM    data 
WHERE   rn = 2
```

How it works:

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` will assign a sequential number to each row based on what's specified in `OVER ()`. In `OVER` i specify to `PARTITION` the rows on customer, that means each group of data on same customer will be numberered separately. Then `ORDER BY Quantity` mean it should order the data based on quantity for each customer - so i can get the 2nd row for each customer ordered by quantity.

Comment: thanks! I have it working! I don't understand it yet completely, but working on it.

Comment: I also now figured out how to write a script with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and get the same result. I've added a second table (Table2) with the same data as in Table1. The given answers by Horia and @Mureinik are nicer, but I state the beneath anyway. Also for my own understanding. 

WITH a AS ( SELECT Customer, Quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Quantity) rn FROM Table1 )
SELECT DISTINCT a.Customer, a.Quantity
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.Customer=b.Customer 
WHERE rn = 2

Answer (score 6):

This can be done quite easily using the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT customer, quantity
FROM   (SELECT customer, quantity,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer 
                                  ORDER BY quantity ASC) AS rn
        FROM   table1) t
WHERE  rn = 2
```

Comment: thanks! I haven't got it working yet, and don't understand it yet completely, but working on it. Any idea why I get errors? (see a printscreen here: http://prntscr.com/85jasz)

Comment: @cybork, put an alias on the subquery.:  `FROM   table1) as t`

Comment: @cybork two stupid mistakes in my query - I was missing a comma after `quantity` and a table alias for the subquery, which SQL-Server insists on. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Mureinik: thanks! Only remaining thing in this query is that DESC would be ASC. Thanks!

Comment: @cybork indeed. I'm so used to using this idiom to "top Nth" issues I use `desc` out of instinct. Fixed.