# Get every second row as a result table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm looking for a `SSIS component` that returns an output, where that output shows every second value from a grouping from a Table1. 'Table1' is the result of previous components. I specifically search for an answer in a component other than the Data source component. There I know a way to do it via the SQL statement. I found the way to that as a result of a previous question: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044334/get-every-second-row-as-a-result-table-in-t-sql).

To clarify my question I made a printscreen (below).  In the red lines I'd like some kind of component that does the grouping as described beneath.

[image]

For example I have the following data (Table1) and want the desired result-list:

```
Table1:  
Customer    Quantity  
A           5  
A           8               (*)  
B           3  
B           5                (*)  
B           11  
C           7  
D           4  
D           23               (*)
```

Desired result-list:

```
Customer    Quantity
A           8
B           5
D           23
```

I think about doing something something with '`select distinct and left outer join`', but I can't get it to work. Possibly I need an row numbering, but can't figure out how to do it. Anyone can help me?

Beneath is the script I used to make and fill Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(Customer nvarchar(1) NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Table1(Customer,Quantity)
VALUES 
('A',5),
('A',8),
('B',3),
('B',5),
('B',11),
('C',7),
('D',4),
('D',23);
```

Comment: It's an OLEDB source with a sql statement that gets every second row, isn't it?   Am I missing something?

Comment: @tab-alleman: yes, you're missing something. Please see the printscreen, also [here](http://prntscr.com/8905hg). I'm looking for a solution that is NOT found via the OLEDB source. I want to know whether there is a way to configure a component, here AFTER the grouping where a temporary table is gotten like 'Table1', that transform Table1 to the desired result-list. Undo my queston with the minus 1 pls. You have a suggestion for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by importing all the rows into a staging table, and then running a stored procedure that moves the 2nd row of each group into the final destination table.

Or, if more SSIS transformations are required, start a second dataflow using the staging table as a source, and getting only the 2nd row of each group with a SQL query.

You have already cited an answered question that shows how to get the second row of each group via TSQL, so that part shouldn't be a problem.

The only other way I know how to do this all in one dataflow is with a custom script transformation, and it would be a lot of code to write, and wouldn't perform as well as the staging table solution, which can use set-based processing instead of row-by-row.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look further into this and see how this suggestion of both the stored procedure and custom script transformation works (I'm new to this). Possibly someone else has another suggestion. PS: I looked up what set based and procedural based is and figure that with set based the procedure of the processing is done by the dbms and with the other you yourself have to tell the dbms how it is processed and the processing of the code is done row by row. Possibly this give way to a new topic but can you confirm my understanding?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you have the essence of the difference between set-based vs procedural.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I got it.