# Get employees still employed in August

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records of employees who are still working and those who resigned in August. Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @MontStart datetime,@MonthEnd datetime
set @MontStart =cast('8/1/2015' as datetime)
set @MonthEnd = cast('8/31/2015' as datetime)

Select * from ( Select EmployeeNo, (Select LastName+','+FirstName from EmpPersonalInfo where EmployeeNo=s1.EmployeeNo) as EmployeeName,(Select Classtitle from Classification where ClassCode=s1.ClassCode) as Classification,Status,s1.EffectivityDateFrom,s1.EffectivityDateTo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeNo ORDER BY Status desc,cast(EffectivityDateTo as date) desc) AS Priority
        FROM Employmenthistory s1)S2 where  Priority=1 and (LTRIM(RTRIM(EmployeeNo))<>'' and NOT(EmployeeNo=''))
         AND (@MontStart >= cast(EffectivityDateFrom as datetime) and (cast(EffectivityDateTo as datetime)>=@MontStart or (cast(EffectivityDateTo as datetime)<=@MonthEnd OR EffectivityDateTo is null)))
order by EmployeeName
```

But this query returns also those employees who resigned in the previous months and years.

Here is the result.

NULL value of EffectivityDateTo column means that employee is still employed (Status=1).

Status 1 = Employed/Active. 
Status 0 = Inactive
Employee 901790 is still active though his EmployedTo is year 2010, he is still set as Active

```
EmployeeNo  |  EmployeeName    |  Status  |   EmployedFrom |  EmployedTo
901790      |  EmpName1        |  1       |   2008-07-28   |    2010-07-31  
902566      |  EmpName2        |  1       |   2013-01-25   |    2013-12-13
902502      |  EmpName3        |  1       |   2012-08-15   |    NULL 
902309      |  EmpName4        |  0       |   2011-07-12   |    2015-08-14
902575      |  EmpName5        |  0       |   2013-03-11   |    2015-08-14
902706      |  EmpName6        |  1       |   2014-03-24   |    2015-10-10
```

Expected result is this:

```
EmployeeNo  |  EmployeeName    |  Status  |   EmployedFrom |  EmployedTo
902502      |  EmpName3        |  1       |   2012-08-15   |    NULL 
902309      |  EmpName4        |  0       |   2011-07-12   |    2015-08-14
902575      |  EmpName5        |  0       |   2013-03-11   |    2015-08-14
902706      |  EmpName6        |  1       |   2014-03-24   |    2015-10-10
```

Comment: Please set up http://sqlfiddle.com with random data, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: You need to fix your WHERE clause. Your first predicate says get any employees that started before August 1. Then you have an AND with 3 OR clauses inside of it. If any of the OR clauses evaluate to true,  you'll get records back. Here's the particular OR clause in that group of 3 that's allowing your query to return the older records: OR (cast(EffectivityDateTo as datetime)<=@MonthEnd. You're saying here that as long as the EffectiveToDate is ANY date earlier than the MonthEnd date(even earlier than start date), include it in the results.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDNCO. I tried modifying my WHERE clause and i was unfortunate to get the desired result. Can you help me pleasE?

Comment: Add the source data to your question to get a good answer. Or put it in sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query could be a lot simpler. I'm not sure what the query would be to get to your first table, but I'll assume that's the `Employmenthistory` table

```
SELECT * FROM Employmenthistory 
WHERE 
(Status = 1 AND EmployedFrom <= @MonthEnd)  
--Get all active employees that started before the end of the specific month

OR (status = 0 AND EmployedTo >= @MonthStart AND EmployedTO <= @MonthEnd)
--Get all employees who stopped working in the given timeframe.
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the first effectivitydatefrom and the last effectivitydateto of an employee but should return only one row. You know, because an employee should start working as probationary and this is one record for his employment. Then if he gets regularized this is another record for his employment and once he resigned, effectivitydateto must be populated.

Comment: @bob-jason-tiamsic: So according to your last comment employees will have multiple entries in the table? That was not clear to me from your original question. Anyway, yes you can by doing a () row_number () over partition by employee order by date desc and add in the where clause that (AND) the row number is 1. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32044334/5218081. The query has to be a bit different because you can't put row_number by formula in where statement.